# How do I publish a Maven project?

Tags: maven-3, codenameone

I just built a very simple project using Maven for the first time. How do I proceed to publish it?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean how to release your project into App\Play store?

Comment: Because if you want to release the app, first you need to generate certificates for the stores. It can be done in cn1 settings menu --> iOS and Android Certificate Wizard.

Comment: No @fnklstn, I have my certificates already generated. I mean how do I generate the final outcome to install it on a device. I want to test it, not release it to a Store.

Comment: If you want just to build the app for real device, choose in maven menu Build Server -> Android Build -> run, and then you can download the `.apk` file on your device from your cn1 dashboard. Check the "Build and Install" in cn1 Developer guide.

Comment: I have been looking for a blog article or something, but no relevant came up in the first two search result pages.

Comment: Developer Guide has instructions for it, it's just a bit outdated since it doesn't include Maven builds. But overall the process is still very similar. If you would like, I can post more detailed answer with screenshots.

Comment: It is ok. I managed to complete the task. Thank you very much for being so helpful @fnklstn.

Comment: The getting started tutorial is up to date and includes that: https://www.codenameone.com/getting-started.html also there's this: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/moving-to-maven.html